# React Native What I'm doing wrong here with constant

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement one functional component.  Here I am doing below, But I'm getting error about props. Could someone help me.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const TextField = () => {
    return (
        <Text> {this.props.title} </Text>
    )
}

export default TextField;

// APP Component
    import TextField from './Components/TextField'
    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <TextField title= "Simple App"/>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: How much time did you spent on debugging? Easier to ask than search?

`const TextField = (props) => {
    return (
        <Text> {props.title} </Text>
    )
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `this.props` is not defined in a functional component. They receive the props as an argument.

Change your `TextField` to take argument `props` and use `props.title`

```
const TextField = (props) => {
    return (
        <Text> {props.title} </Text>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can we add custom props to this?